# taking command line input in different ways

Tags: c++

How can one take command line argument by not using below structure ?

```
 int main ( int argc, char* argv ) {

 }
```

My question is really : how can I  take below input :

```
 ./executableProgramName   inputX inputY inputZ inputT
```

in any function ?

```
in foo () {

 // what should I write so that I can get same effect 
}
```

- Are there any other way for taking command line input ?

Comment: You cannot. Command line arguments are *only* exposed to the `main` function. Just grab them there and store them for future use. (Yes, there's also Windows-specific stuff, but that's not standard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best way is to forward the handling of command line arguments into an object, or simply a function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void handle_commandline_args(const std::vector<std::string>& args){
    ...
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    handle_commandline_args(std::vector<string>(argv[0], argv[0] + argc));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method specified by the standard for getting command line arguments is the argc and argv parameters passed to the entry point function `main`. There's no other standard method.

Some platforms offer non-standard methods. For example, if you're on Windows you can use `GetCommandLineW`

Here's an example that uses some C++11 stuff too.

```
#include <ShellAPI.h> // for CommandLineToArgvW
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>

int main() {
#ifdef WIN32
    LPWSTR *szArglist;
    int argc;
    szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(),&argc);
    if(NULL==szArglist) {
       std::cerr << "CommandLineToArgvW failed\n";
    }
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert; // codecvt_utf8 or codecvt<char16_t,char,mbstate_t> should work (will work once the char16_t specialization of codecvt works)
    vector<string> args;
    for(int i=0;i<argc;++i) {
        args.push_back(convert.to_bytes(szArglist[i]));
    }
#endif //ifdef WIN32

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not arbitrarily get the command-line arguments from any function. In C++, the only way command-line arguments are passed in is through the char* array in the main function.

If you want them to be accessible from anywhere, consider keeping them in a global variable, or passing them into each necessary function call. For example:

```
int argumentCount;
char **argumentArray;

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    argumentCount = argc;
    argumentArray = argv;
}

int foo()
{
    std::cout << argumentArray[0]; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with MSVC++, then you can use below win32 API to get command line arguments anytime in your program:

- [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, this makes your code non-standard. So it is better if you use `main(int argc, char *argv[])` to get the command line arguments and save them for later use, e.g to be used by other functions.

Comment: In the case of Windows using the standard C++ functionality is pretty useless for other than toy programs; e.g. an arbitrary filename can't be passed. So `GetCommandLine` and its parsing cousin are necessary. And even though non-standard, infinitely better than the mechanism that Does Not Work(TM).